# RenderAction to generate dropdown?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, renderaction

I'm having a mvc form which among other things contains an int that should be mapped to text strings displayed in a dropdown.

```
MyViewModel
{
    ...other fields...
    int Level { get; set; }
    ...other fields...
}
```

Is it possible to use RenderAction for the Level field and generate the dropdown from a separate action?

I hope this question is coherent, I'm quitting coffee and my head isn't where it usually is.

Comment: You are missing the drop down items collection from this view model. How do you expect to generate a drop down list from a simple integer property?

Comment: The items are fetched from a database call. The integer corresponds to one of them. I'm hoping not to have the dropdown items in the viewmodel but rather in a separate action. That is what I'm asking if it's possible.

Comment: if the drop down list is part of the partial view that is returned by the RenderAction it would make sense to include the list as part of the view model.

Comment: Usually I do it that way. But this list will be used in several other places so I felt it was compelling with an even looser coupling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although many people will advise (rightly so) not to do this but if you insist you can do something like

```
public VMDropDown
{
     IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items{get;set;}
     public string InputName{get;set;}
}
```

as you want to reuse this dropdown you can accept its html name attribute as action method parameter

```
public ActionResult(string inputName)
{
    VMDropDown model = new VMDropDown();
    model.InpuName = inputName;
    model.Items = //populate Text and Value property of each SelectListItem from db
    return View(model);

}
```

in your view you can write something like

```
<:Html.Dropdown(Model.InputName, Model.Items)%>
```

Comment: That makes sense. Default select is also easy to do with yet an action parameter.

Comment: How come you think it's a bad idea?

Comment: ideally your Dropdown should be generated by same view model which contains property you are editing. This kind of reusability will introduce unwanted complexity in the system and you will find yourself adding more parameters to your action method and properties to your view model to meet upcomming needs of rendering this dropdown list

Comment: I see what you mean. Do you think there are occasions where the concept is a good idea? IE: to completely leave the rendering of a particular item up to the view and not the viewmodel?

Comment: @CarlR i have used this approach in my project but with the passage of time you find it difficult to maintain such code. i.e an actionresult that is just rendering the dropdown and if project is big you have no idea on how many places it is used. However, if you have small project or you plan to use this action method in just couple of views then it is fine

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your experiences. :)